# How to figure if the certificate SHA-256 digest in the Play Integrity verdict is valid?

Tags: android, hash, google-api, google-play-integrity-api

I'm working with the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview) and I'm looking at the  SHA-256 digest in the app integrity part [of the verdict](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#application-integrity-field).

Here is what the doc says about this digest:

```
// The sha256 digest of app certificates.
// This field is populated iff appRecognitionVerdict != UNEVALUATED.
certificateSha256Digest: ["6a6a1474b5cbbb2b1aa57e0bc3"]
```

The goal of this verdict part is to verify the app integrity and I assume that this digest has been generated from the version of the app to be evaluated. However, I don't know how to decide it is a valid one.

I would expect that if I find the certificate that is used to sign the app, and I use gradle to generate a signing report, it would include the SHA-256 digest of the certificate, but the SHA-256 generated by `./gradlew signingReport` doesn't match the one returned in the verdict.

Am I missing something here? How to find what SHA-256 digests are valid?

Comment: signingReport provides sha256 digest in the hex form, while Play Integrity API field provides it in base64 web-safe no-wrap no-padding form. You can make conversion using `echo CE:RT:DI:GE:ST:IN:HE:XF:OR:MM | xxd -r -p | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '='`

Comment: Perfect thank you @AbzalSerekov ! I was starting to wonder if it was a conversion but I wouldn't guess it. Please post it as an answer, I'll accept it, ideally explaining why it's necessary to transform the `+` into `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signingReport` provides sha256 digest in the hex form, while Play Integrity API field provides it in base64 web-safe no-wrap no-padding form. You can make conversion using

```
echo CE:RT:DI:GE:ST:IN:HE:XF:OR:MM | xxd -r -p | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '='
```

Note that the reason for transforming + to - is because base64 web-safe form (see specification [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5))

Comment: I wonder why it is so complicated: a text encoding within another text encoding.